# In-App-Purchase sandbox testing - Purchasing Not Supported in your region

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I developing an App for Ukrainian people with In-App-Purchase. When I add sandbox tester with Ukraine location and try purchase I am getting this alert [image].

If I use some other location, Russia for example - thats good. My App is for Ukrainian people and I am disturbed by this.

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apple is a US company and are therefore they are prohibited from carrying out business transactions with the Crimea region of the  Ukraine as per [executive order 13685](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Documents/ukraine_eo4.pdf) section 1 (a) (iii)

> (iii) the exportation, reexportation, sale, or supply, directly or indirectly, from the United States, or by a United States person, wherever located, of any goods, services, or technology to the Crimea region of Ukraine;

I suspect that since you don't enter an address, just a store, when creating a sandbox user, they don't know which region you are in and they default to blocking the purchase. In production, a user has a registered address which lets Apple block purchases more selectively.

It looks like you will need to complete your testing with a user from another store.

Comment: many thanks for your answear, but I am located in Odessa which is not Crimea region or i have paid iOS App's (without IAP) for Ukraine and don't have some problems. What are you think this issue only in sandbox?

Comment: @DmitriyKulakoff Have you fixed that?

Comment: @Oleg No, I ignored that, I have more time to release.

Comment: I've got this error once, and now keep getting it every time. Even after I logged out from that Ukrainian sandbox account, deleted an app, restarted the phone. AppStore doesn't ask to login anymore, just showing the error.

Answer (score 11):

Note: iOS 12+ Only

Sign in into your main account. Then you will see option for SANDBOX ACCOUNT.
Use not Ukrainian test account and test your purchases.

Sandbox Account Image:
[image: SANDBOX ACCOUNT IMAGE]

Comment: This is what helped me, thanks!
You need to delete your Ukrainian account SANDBOX first and then create a new NON-Ukrainian one.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create the sandbox tester, related to not Ukrainian Itunes Store. Something like this:
[image]

Many thanks to [Mike](https://www.facebook.com/mike.timashov) form [Cherrypie Studio](https://cherrypiestudio.com/en/home/)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error that was caused by using test user with Ukrainian country. But that error didn't go away even after I logged out from that account, created new non Ukrainian one, logged in(many times), logged out (many times), deleted an app, restarted the phone...

The only thing that helped was device reset. Only after that system stopped showing me that error and I finally saw App Store login window again.